# How to do simple calculation between two arrays together

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and I want to sum between the multipliers and numbers.
My result is correct but I don't know how to automate this because my `multipliers` and `numbers` have a lot of numbers. `numbers` and `multipliers` have always the same size

Any help please :/

```js
const multipliers = [1, 1.5, 4];

const numbers = [209, 4, 23];

const result = 1 * 209 + 1.5 * 4 + 23 * 4;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> Use a loop

Comment: Or the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const multipliers = [1, 1.5, 4];

const numbers = [209, 4, 23];

const result = numbers.reduce((pre, cur, index) => pre + cur*multipliers[index], 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const multipliers = [1, 1.5, 4];

const numbers = [209, 4, 23];
let result = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < multipliers.length; i++) {
    result += (multipliers[i] * numbers[i]);
}
console.log(result);
```

This should work

Comment: Please refrain from answering such low-effort questions that could be solved with some research (either by asking "Google" or by reading a tutorial).

Answer (score -1):

Use the following **code** for your problem.

```js
const multipliers = [1, 1.5, 4];

const numbers = [209, 4, 23];

let result = [];

//We're assuming that the lengths of both the arrays are same
for (let i = 0; i < multipliers.length; i++) {
    result.push(multipliers[i]*numbers[i]);
}
console.log(result.reduce((a,b)=>a+b));
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but just FYI,  you don't need two loops.